# Android Custom Component doesn't show anything after inflate

Tags: android, components, android-inflate

Trying to create a custom component that gets it's layout from an XML file (box.xml).  I have gone through a couple of tutorials but just can't seem to get anything to display. Below is the constructors for my custom component and the code does get executed without errors.

```
public class MyView extends LinearLayout {
    //Constructor required for inflation from resource file
    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);        
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view=layoutInflater.inflate (R.layout.box, this);                        
        Log.d("CONSTRUCTOR 2", "TESTER");        
    }
}
```

I add the component to a layout with this:

```
<com.mysample.MyView android:layout_width="50dp" android:layout_height="38dp" android:background="#FF000000" />
```

The black block does appear on the screen but not with the layout of the xml file I inflate it with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add the created view to the linear layout.

```
    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        View view = inflate(context, R.layout.box, null);
        addView(view);
    }
```

This should work. Do you see the Log in your Logcat by the way?

Here is the box.xml (Sample one). You need to use the fully qualified class name of the MyView wherever you want to use it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<com.beanie.samples.drawing.MyView
android:id="@+id/whiteboardView1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"></com.beanie.samples.drawing.MyView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Check this [sample project here](http://code.google.com/p/myandroidwidgets/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FCustomLinearLayout).

Comment: If I add this to the constructor at the bottom I get and error: this.addView(view);

Error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent.

Comment: View view=layoutInflater.inflate (R.layout.box, null);

Comment: This executes but displays nothing: 

View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tile, null);                                
    this.addView(view);

Comment: This works for me. Can you show your box xml as well? You can directly use the inflate method of the view class instead of creating an instance of the LayoutInflater

Comment: I cant post the code here because I can only post 550 characters. Is there another way I can show you the code? I really appreciate you trying to help me with this.

Comment: I will split the file in two:

Part 1:


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_height="0dip" android:layout_weight=".64" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
     <View android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight=".88" android:layout_width="0dip" android:id="@+id/view1" android:background="#FFFFFFFF"></View>

Comment: Part 2:

     <View android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight=".12" android:layout_width="0dip" android:id="@+id/view3" android:background="#FF777777"></View>
    </LinearLayout>
    <View android:layout_height="0dip" android:layout_weight=".12" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/view2" android:background="#FF000000"></View>                 
</LinearLayout>

Comment: If you use the above xml file (box.xml) you will see it is basically just a couple of views with different background colors. If I can have the basic .java file that will use this xml file I can work on from there. But at the moment nothing from this xml file even appears on the screen.

Comment: View? Well, you should be using your class name. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Updated my code to be like yours. File loads and I can confirm all code executes without any errors as I put a Log.d() at the end of the constructor and it shows up in LogCat. But still nothing comes up. I can also confirm that I use the fully qualified class name in my layout file where I want my component to appear. The component does appear because if I set the background color I can see it. It just doesnt snow anything from box.xml. ALSO if I load box.xml by itself through an Activity it works perfectly. I will start a new project from scratch and redo everything :(

Comment: Ok used your sample project to create a new project and got it working. This will help me move it over into my project and move forward. Thank you so much for the example and your time.